# getting null in responce from graphRequest while posting the video to facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook, video, share

I am getting the Access token after login into Facebook. But I am unable to get response from the graph response.I am Trying to post the video from my app Here is my code.Please, any one helps me to resolve this issue.

```
private void postvideo(byte[] VideoBytes, String filePath)
{
    String url;
    url = "/me/videos";
    AccessToken token_new = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();


    if (token_new != null) {
        Bundle param = new Bundle();
        param.putByteArray("video." + getFileExt(filePath), VideoBytes);
        param.putString("description", "sample video");


        new GraphRequest(token_new,url, param, HttpMethod.POST, new GraphRequest.Callback() {

            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                Log.e("New Post", "Res =" + response.toString());
                Toast.makeText(activity, "response."+response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                if (response != null && response.getJSONObject() != null && response.getJSONObject().has("id")) {
                    Log.e("New Post", "Success");
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Video posted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Error in posting Video."+response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
               /* setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent());
                finish();*/
            }
        }).executeAsync();
    }


}
```

this is the response I am getting

{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#100) No permission to publish the video}

Comment: Check whether your access token has the required permissions to post a video https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/ To publish a video to a user profile, you need publish_actions permission. Also see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads

Comment: the video is posting successfully if i share to developers facebook account. Unable to share other facebook accounts.